# Dynamically resize images linked to JLabels in a GridLayout layoutmanager

Tags: java, image, swing, resize, grid-layout

**Current implementation layout:**
[image: implementation layout]

((EDIT: added
**Code:** ))

```
private JPanel panelCenter;
private List<BufferedImage> listCreatedImages;
public ChooseCircuitPanel(List<BufferedImage> listCreatedImages) {
        this.listCreatedImages = listCreatedImages;
        initiate();
}
private void initiate() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(50, 50));
        panelCenter = new JPanel();
        LayoutManager theLayout = new GridLayout(0, 3, 0, 0);
        panelCenter.setLayout(theLayout);
        panelCenter.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        for (BufferedImage bufferedImage : listCreatedImages) {
            ImageIcon theImage = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);
            JLabel lblForImage = new JLabel(theImage);
            lblForImage.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            panelCenter.add(lblForImage);
        }
        this.add(panelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

**Situation:**

We want to display a race circuit here. A circuit should be displayed by placing standards tiles next to each other. It should be possible to resize the window, and with that, the circuit tiles should also resize.

((**EDIT**: bit more info: The race circuit data is stored on a server and the desktop application has to translate the data to a visual thing, by placing some standard tiles in the right order. ))

((**EDIT**: we are not allowed to use any external library. It should be doable by **only using Java Swing code**.))

I thought about placing the images in a JLabel and placing these JLabels in a panel with GridLayout as layout manager.

Using a GridLayout - I thought - it should be rather easy to get to a solution:
the components in the GridLayout (= JLabels) already scale and do exactly what I want.
**Now, it would only be a matter of finding a way to resize the images so they fill the JLabels**.

As you can see: right now, the images have a fixed size and don't scale at all.

I browsed a bit and saw lots of solutions that boil down to using **Graphics2D** and **super.paintComponent**, etc.

**But most of these solutions had nothing to do with a GridLayout.**
So conclusive question:
**Is there an easier solution aside from using Graphics2D, etc. knowing that I use a GridLayout?**

If not, I will of course use Graphics2D, etc. but I'm now just exploring my options. :)

((EDIT: **SOLVED** The tiles now neatly fit on each other. Don't mind the misalignments, that's our fault.))
[image: result]

Comment: Have you looked at [`JMCAD`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmcad)?

Comment: I think you are a little misunderstanding the question (my fault, will add this also to start post):

It's not a race circuit design tool or anything.

The race circuit data is stored on a server and the desktop application has to translate the data to a visual thing, by placing some standard tiles in the right order. :)

I will delete the design concept: it's not really necessary actually.

Comment: `we are not allowed to use any external library.` - what is GridView? That is not a standard class.

Comment: From the [description of grid view](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/gridview/info), I got the impression the code used [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html).  Please confirm/refute my presumption in a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Comment: @camickr I'm so sorry, I meant GridLayout. One of the standard layout managers in Java Swing. I changed the text now.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm so sorry, I meant GridLayout. One of the standard layout managers in Java Swing. I changed the text now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no Swing components that do what you want so you will need to write your own code.

The easiest approach would be to use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) on your JLabel.

Or another approach is to create your own custom component that dynamically scales the image as it is painted. Something like the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) which has code that allows you to scale or tile an image.

Comment: I had already come across Darryl's Stretch Icon class, but didn't try it yet because I first wanted to hear other potential solutions.

But I now inserted his code, and it works wonderful and how I expected! Thanks. And thanks, Darryl.

Answer (score 1):

Given the nature of the view, I would recommend abandoning images altogether and instead implement the rendering in an [`Icon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html).  Presuming you can make an icon scale with the label.